# Extremly Slow SQL query with subquery and "HAVING"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query where I want to count how many entries in "user" have multiple entries in "usernames"

```
SELECT usernames.NAME,
    COUNT(user.id)
FROM user
INNER JOIN user_username ON user.id = user_username.user_id
INNER JOIN usernames ON user_username.user_username_id = usernames.id
WHERE 
    user.datecreated BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-01'
    AND user.id IN 
        (
            SELECT user_id
            FROM user_username
            GROUP BY user_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
GROUP BY usernames.NAME
ORDER BY user.id DESC
```

The query works, but is too slow, any ideas what I could do to speed up this query?

Comment: How long does running JUST the subquery take?

Comment: You should review the `EXPLAIN PLAN` of your sentence.

Comment: Query takes 183 seconds and the subquery just 0.063 seconds

Comment: first thing I would do is make sure your Fk fields are indexed.

Comment: Include Actual Execution Plan (Ctrl + M) and execute the query. Then see if it doesn't suggest anything. I suspect indexes might be the issue on one of your tables querying.

Comment: user.id, usernames.id & user_username.id are primary, user_username.user_id & user_username.user_username_id are foreing keys

Comment: Why do you order by user id, when it is not even in the select list, and is not grouped by? This would not even be allowed in ISO SQL.

Comment: Do you have index on datecreated  column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does breaking the query up like this help?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE QualifiedUserIDs AS (
SELECT user_id
FROM user_username
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);

SELECT usernames.NAME,
    COUNT(user.id)
FROM user
INNER JOIN QualifiedUserIDs quids ON quids.user_id = user.id 
INNER JOIN user_username ON user.id = user_username.user_id
INNER JOIN usernames ON user_username.user_username_id = usernames.id
WHERE 
    user.datecreated BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-01'

GROUP BY usernames.NAME
ORDER BY user.id DESC
```

Comment: I went with this solution. Works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague but try this:

```
SELECT  usernames.name, COUNT(user.id) 
FROM user 
INNER JOIN user_username ON user.id = user_username.user_id
INNER JOIN usernames     ON user_username.user_username_id = usernames.id
WHERE 
    user.datecreated BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-01'
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) where user_id = user.id from user_username) > 1

GROUP BY usernames.name
ORDER BY user.id DESC
```

I don't think you actualy have to group by user_id to get the users with more user_names.

Edit I think this is better. Make left outer joins (you will get multiple lines with repeating user.id) and then group by them.

```
SELECT  user.id, COUNT(usernames.name) -- to show the number of usernames a user has 
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_username ON user.id = user_username.user_id
LEFT JOIN usernames     ON user_username.user_username_id = usernames.id
WHERE user.datecreated BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-09-01'
GROUP BY user.id
HAVING COUNT(usernames.name) > 1
ORDER BY user.id DESC
```

On a side note...`user`, `usernames.name`, `user_username.user_id`, `user.id`, `user_username.user_username_id`, `usernames.id`, `user_id=user.id` makes my head spin...

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad example. The original query didn't have those names , but I'm not allowed to show the real names of the tables etc...